# Preventing multithreaded apps from running out of memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I've written a small, in house C# program which batch converts between various file formats, mostly relying on other API's.  Currently, the UI spawns a BackgroundWorker (not a Thread) to handle the conversions, and then fills a queue with the requests which empties as the worker completes jobs.  The queue object themselves are very small (3 Strings to tell the worker what to do) and don't contribute greatly to the program's memory footprint.  I've been fairly draconian with my memory management (disposing of Images when finished with them, and manually garbage collecting at certain points.) Still, the program tends to use about 100 MB of memory at a time, and uses about 50% of total CPU time. It seems like if I naively implemented threading, it would quickly run out of system memory (unless the CLR does some sort of magic I don't know about.)

Is there a simple/efficient way to spawn threads to prevent the system from running out of memory besides catching OutOfMemory exceptions and rolling back the thread that died (seems very inefficient, but there's no way to preserve state without using prohibitive amounts of memory)?

Comment: How many threads are we talking? You mention the UI plus one worker... but that shouldn't be a huge issue; are you spawning *lots* of threads?

Comment: I have one BackgroundWorker object (not a Thread) currently. I would like to add more to allow greater CPU utilization but preventing the system running out of memory.  Like I said, the UI with one worker takes up to 100 MB of ram, so even adding a few more threads might be an issue. Batch jobs can routinely be over 100 files long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) to spawn the conversions you will automatically get a limit on how many threads that are running. The ThreadPool manages this internally and will process queued calls as soon as a pool thread becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Put a limit on the queue size and make sender wait if it's full. You would have to find the right queue size limit empirically though.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory exceptions can be tricky and maybe caused by fragmented memory, not actually running out of memory.  Therefore they can be tricky to track down.

Tess from Microsoft product support in Sweeden (http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) has got a good number of posts on tracking down memory where memory is going to help with this process.

A good profile of your app could also help.  JetBrains have a good one as is AQTime.

Answer (score 0):

Using 100MB of memory is not a lot for an image processing application.

Also, in .net when you get an OutOfMemory exception the entire process dies, you can't recover from this.

If you need more memory (or, more correctly, more address space) than the system can give you can either page memory in and out as you use it or switch to 64bit.

You can limit the queue size to make sure the only "heavy" memory user is the worker thread, you can have more than one worker thread, that will increase your memory usage but will also empty the queue faster, just remember that in a CPU intensive operations like this having more threads than CPU cores is inefficient.

You talk about "naively implemented threading", multi-threading is full of pitfalls - a naive implementation will be inefficient and full of bugs.